# Tomcat classpath loader javax.mail.Session conflict with spring-boot-starter-mail

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, jakarta-mail

Trying to deploy a Spring Boot app on Tomcat (not the embedded Tomcat). I have configured a Java mail session on the Tomcat server config, and I'm trying to access it as a JNDI value in my app. For some reason, my app gets an error and shows this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The local resource link [support] that refers to global resource [mail/support] was expected to return an instance of [javax.mail.Session] but returned an instance of [javax.mail.Session]
        at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceLinkFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceLinkFactory.java:163)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:840)
```

I have included `javax.mail.jar` in the Tomcat `/lib` folder. I also have `spring-boot-starter-mail` included in my `pom.xml`

I've tried removing the `javax.mail.jar` from Tomcat's lib, but that causes an error on Tomcat start because it can't create the mail session. I've also tried removing spring-boot-starter-mail, but that interferes with some of my code that requires JavaMailSender and other mail components. I've tried messing with the JNDI import and stuff like that, but to no avail. I've also tried checking the version of the mail jar included by `spring-boot-starter-mail`, and updating the jar in Tomcat to match. I've also checked my transitive dependencies in Maven to see if a different mail implementation is being pulled in, and there's nothing. So I'm kind of all out of ideas.

Here's where I'm getting the JNDI value in my web.xml:

```xml
<resource-ref>
        <description>The mail session configured in Tomcat</description>
        <res-ref-name>mail/support</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.mail.Session</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

Here's what I have configured in Tomcat's `server.xml`:

```xml
<GlobalNamingResources>
<Resource name="mail/support"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.mail.Session"
              mail.smtp.host="smtp.XXX.XXX"
              mail.smtp.user="support"
              mail.smtp.from="support@XXX.org" />
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

And here's what's in context.xml:

```xml
<Context>
<ResourceLink global="mail/support" name="mail/support" type="javax.mail.Session" />
</Context>
```

I'd like to be able to use `spring-boot-starter-mail`, and use a globally configured JNDI mail session. I don't know if those are just incompatible wishes, but I don't see why they should be.

Comment: The problem definitely seems to be caused by the fact that the JavaMail classes are both in the Tomcat lib folder and in your application.  You need to find a way to exclude them from your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the solution was indeed what @Bill Shannon suggested. I had to include the `com.sun.mail` dependency with the Maven `provided` scope. My particular issue was that the project was already using the `spring-boot-starter-mail` dependency, which includes the `com.sun.mail` jar. So I had to exclude that from my Maven dependency. So the complete Maven dependency related to mail stuff looks like this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

That seems a little obvious now. I think my main source of confusion was the weird Tomcat error message. Thanks for anyone who took a look at this, hopefully this resolves the issue for someone else!